# Send email alert to parent record's related contact field

Tags: email-alert

I am trying to build an email alert to send to related contact. However, the contact field is on the parent object of current object. So I am thinking how can I walkaround this issue.

Formula fields don't take email as the return type so I can't build a formula field based on that. Trigger is viable but a bit pain now at this point. Is there any other approach rather than trigger?

Comment: did you try process builder?

Answer (score 0):

U can achive it by either process builder or flow.
https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000swe9QAA